# Anything akin to Silver Efex Pro for processing high quality B&W on Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, software-recommendation, photography

I am trying to improve my b&w photography skills and have been advised by a few photographers that I respect to use Silver Efex Pro for post processing my images.  Since this is a windows/mac product and I am trying to find Linux software that can compete with with windows for specific tasks, I would like to find a product that will work for this.  I have tried Dark Table, Gimp, and a few others, but they seem to fall short on good B&W.

Any photographers out there that shoot good B&W that might have a suggestion?

Comment: You could try running the program in WINE

Comment: I have not used WINE, but may have to investigate it.  I've been told that Lightroom and it's plugins (of which, Silver Efex is one) will not work correectly on WINE.  No personal knowledge of this.

Comment: Another thing you could do is run the program in a Windows VM. Virtual box has a feature where you can hide the VM's desktop, and so a program running in the VM would appear as if it were running nativly on Ubuntu.